# How can I extract location information from adjacency matrix in R?

Tags: r, adjacency-matrix

I have adjacency matrix as below:

```
> matrix(c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0),ncol=4,byrow=T)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    0    0
[2,]    1    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0    1
[4,]    0    0    1    0
```

Question 1: how can I get the corresponding information like:
`2 5 7 10 12 15`from R?

Question 2: how can I get the location information of '1's in each row like:

```
2 
1 3 
2 4 
3
```

or `2 1 3 2 4 3`from R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `which` on a logical matrix

```
which(m1 == 1)
#[1]  2  5  7 10 12 15
```

---

If we need the column index in a `list`

```
sapply(split(!!m1, col(m1)), which)
```

Or as a vector

```
na.omit(na_if(c(t(m1 * col(m1))), 0))
#[1] 2 1 3 2 4 3
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0),ncol = 4,byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks. What about the location of '1' at each row, like:```2 1 3 2 4 3```?

Comment: Use `apply()` (or similar) over rows, e.g. `apply(m1, 1, function(x) which(x == 1))`

Comment: @JohnColby - or use `which(m1 == 1, arr.ind=TRUE)` which will return the row/col indexes.

Comment: @ChestnutT  My answer was based on your initial question and I didn't know that you will update with more questions

Answer (score 0):

```
m <- matrix(c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0),ncol=4,byrow=T)
mm <- m == 1
which(mm)
#[1]  2  5  7 10 12 15
apply(mm, 1, which)
#[[1]]
#[1] 2
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 3
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 2 4
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 3
```

perhaps also see `raster::adjacency`